# Interesection of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If it is given that ABC is a {0}, where A, B and C are sets,

then is it true that ABCD is also {0} or null set, where D is also a set

ABC means will mean intersection of A, B and C.

Further, the way I looked at it was

ABCD = A(BCD) = A{0} = {0}

Is my conclusion of ABCD = null set true?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but your reasoning is strange. $A \cap B \cap C \cap D = (A \cap B \cap C) \cap D $

Comment: So by associativity, I can say this too right?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I felt so too, Is there a better way to show it?

Comment: You can simply suppose it is not empty, then there is an element in ABCD, then that element is in A, and in B, and in C, ... etc

Comment: Please, note that the *null* set, or *empty* set is not $\{ \emptyset \}$, but $\emptyset$ or $\{  \}$.  $\{  \}$ has no elemets inside, while $\{ \emptyset \}$ has one element inside, precisely : $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(A \cap B \cap C \cap D) \subseteq (A \cap B \cap C) = \varnothing \Rightarrow (A \cap B \cap C \cap D) = \varnothing .
$$